# оптимизация при трансляции данных с локального MSSQL в MYSQL через C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, оптимизация

В общем у меня есть некий проект который работает по локальной сети на бд MSSQL. Появился необходимость выводить данные в интернет для работы с ним через телефон и другие аппараты в сети интернет. Пока что оптимального способа вывода я еще не нашел и нахожусь в поиске. Какой способ вы можете посоветовать?

Мой нынешний способ (слегка урезанный для понимания):

1. Процедура на MYSQL принимающий и записывающий данные

   ```
   CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' PROCEDURE sp_dk_add_cat_material 
   (
     IN  p_cat_id       int,
     IN  p_material_id  int,
     IN  p_modify_date  datetime
   )
   BEGIN

   DECLARE  v_material_id int DEFAULT 0;
   select material_id INTO v_material_id  FROM tbl_mg_category_material
   where tbl_mg_category_material.material_id=p_material_id;

   if (v_material_id=0)  then 
      insert into tbl_mg_category_material 
                 (
                  cat_id,
                  material_id,
                  modify_date
                 ) 
      values 
                 (
                  p_cat_id,
                  p_material_id,
                  p_modify_date
      );
   ELSE 
      update  tbl_mg_category_material
              set cat_id=p_cat_id,
                  material_id=p_material_id,
                  modify_date=p_modify_date
      where material_id=p_material_id;
     END IF;
   END
   ```
2. Код на C# отправляющий данные в процедуру на MYSQL

   ```
   public static void sp_dk_add_cat_materialMYSQL(int cat_id, int material_id, DateTime modify_date)
   {
       MySqlConnection _MYsqlconn = DK_MySQL_Conn.Connection;
       MySqlCommand _cmd_add_cat_material = new MySqlCommand();
       _cmd_add_cat_material.Connection = _MYsqlconn;
       _cmd_add_cat_material.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       _cmd_add_cat_material.CommandText = "sp_dk_add_cat_material";

       _cmd_add_cat_material.Parameters.Add("p_cat_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = cat_id;
       _cmd_add_cat_material.Parameters.Add("p_material_id", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = material_id;
       _cmd_add_cat_material.Parameters.Add("p_modify_date", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = modify_date;
       try
       {
           _MYsqlconn.Open();
           _cmd_add_cat_material.CommandTimeout = 200;
           _cmd_add_cat_material.ExecuteNonQuery();
           _MYsqlconn.Close();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
   }

   private void Btn_insToMySQL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       BindingSource _bds, _bdscategory, _bdscatMaterials = new BindingSource();
       _bds = _bdsMSSQLitems;
       _bdscategory = dk_Query.get_tbl_category();
       _bdscatMaterials = dk_Query.get_category_material();
       SplashScreenManager.ShowForm(typeof(WaitForm1));
       SplashScreenManager.Default.SendCommand(WaitForm1.WaitFormCommand.SetProgressBarMaximum, _bds.Count+_bdscategory.Count+_bdscatMaterials.Count);
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
       int _splasPosition = 0;
       SplashScreenManager.Default.SendCommand(WaitForm1.WaitFormCommand.SetLabelText, "Kategoriýalar...");
       for (int i=0;i<_bdscategory.Count;i++)
       {
           _splasPosition++;
           SplashScreenManager.Default.SendCommand(WaitForm1.WaitFormCommand.SetProgressBarPosition, _splasPosition);
           DataRowView drc = (DataRowView)_bdscategory[i];
           int cat_id = 0;
           try { cat_id = Convert.ToInt32(drc["cat_id"]); }
           catch { }
           string cat_name = "";
           try { cat_name = Convert.ToString(drc["cat_name"]); }
           catch { }
           string cat_desc = "";
           try { cat_desc = Convert.ToString(drc["cat_desc"]); }
           catch { }
           string cat_image_path = "";
           try { cat_image_path = Convert.ToString(drc["cat_image_path"]); }
           catch { }
           int published = 0;
           try { published = Convert.ToInt32(drc["published"]); }
           catch { }
           int cat_order = 0;
           try { cat_order = Convert.ToInt32(drc["cat_order"]); }
           catch { }

           dk_Query.sp_dk_add_categoryMYSQL(cat_id, cat_name, cat_desc, cat_image_path, published, cat_order);
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < _bdscatMaterials.Count; i++)
       {
           _splasPosition++;
           SplashScreenManager.Default.SendCommand(WaitForm1.WaitFormCommand.SetProgressBarPosition, _splasPosition);
           DataRowView drc = (DataRowView)_bdscatMaterials[i];
           int cat_id = 0;
           try { cat_id = Convert.ToInt32(drc["cat_id"]); }
           catch { }
           int material_id = 0;
           try { material_id = Convert.ToInt32(drc["material_id"]); }
           catch { }
           DateTime modify_date =Convert.ToDateTime("01.01.1900 00:00");
           try { modify_date = Convert.ToDateTime(drc["modify_date"]); }
           catch { }

           dk_Query.sp_dk_add_cat_materialMYSQL(cat_id, material_id, modify_date);
       }

       for (int i = 0; i < _bds.Count; i++)
       {
           _splasPosition++;
           SplashScreenManager.Default.SendCommand(WaitForm1.WaitFormCommand.SetProgressBarPosition, _splasPosition);
           DataRowView drc = (DataRowView)_bds[i];
           int material_id = 0;
           try { material_id = Convert.ToInt32(drc["material_id"]); }
           catch { }

           if (material_id != 0)
           {
               DateTime modify_date = Convert.ToDateTime("01.01.1900 00:01");
               try { modify_date = Convert.ToDateTime(drc["modify_date"]); }
               catch { }
               DateTime _logmodify_date = Convert.ToDateTime("01.01.1900 00:00");
               try
               {
                   _logmodify_date = Convert.ToDateTime(dk_Query.get_modify_date_by_matId(material_id)["modify_date"]);
               }
               catch { }
               if (modify_date > _logmodify_date)
               {
                   string material_code = "";
                   try { material_code = Convert.ToString(drc["material_code"]); }
                   catch { };
                   string material_name = "";
                   try { material_name = Convert.ToString(drc["material_name"]); }
                   catch { }
                   string m_cat_name = "";
                   try { m_cat_name = Convert.ToString(drc["m_cat_name"]); }
                   catch { }
                   string a_status_name = "";
                   try { a_status_name = Convert.ToString(drc["a_status_name"]); }
                   catch { }
                   int firm_id = 1;
                   try { firm_id = Convert.ToInt32(drc["firm_id"]); }
                   catch { }
                   int m_cat_id = 0;
                   try { m_cat_id = Convert.ToInt32(drc["m_cat_id"]); }
                   catch { }
                   int unit_id = 1;
                   try { unit_id = Convert.ToInt32(drc["unit_id"]); }
                   catch { }
                   int a_status_id = 1;
                   try { a_status_id = Convert.ToInt32(drc["a_status_id"]); }
                   catch { }
                   int mat_whousetotal_id = 0;
                   try { mat_whousetotal_id = Convert.ToInt32(drc["mat_whousetotal_id"]); }
                   catch { }
                   float mat_whousetotal_amount = 0;
                   try { mat_whousetotal_amount = Convert.ToSingle(drc["mat_whousetotal_amount"]); }
                   catch { }
                   float sale_price = 0;
                   try { sale_price = Convert.ToSingle(drc["sale_price"]); }
                   catch { }
                   float mat_purch_price = 0;
                   try { mat_purch_price = Convert.ToSingle(drc["mat_purch_price"]); }
                   catch { }
                   int wh_id = 1;
                   try { wh_id = Convert.ToInt32(drc["wh_id"]); }
                   catch { }
                   int p_id = 0;
                   try { p_id = Convert.ToInt32(drc["p_id"]); }
                   catch { }
                   int unit_det_id = 1;
                   try { unit_det_id = Convert.ToInt32(drc["unit_det_id"]); }
                   catch { }
                   //int image_pict = 0;
                   //try { image_pict = Convert.ToInt32(drc["image_pict"]); }
                   //catch { }
                   string unit_det_code = "";
                   try { unit_det_code = Convert.ToString(drc["unit_det_code"]); }
                   catch { }
                   string unit_det_name = "";
                   try { unit_det_name = Convert.ToString(drc["unit_det_name"]); }
                   catch { }
                   string unit_code = "";
                   try { unit_code = Convert.ToString(drc["unit_code"]); }
                   catch { }
                   float stock_max_level = 0;
                   try { stock_max_level = Convert.ToSingle(drc["stock_max_level"]); }
                   catch { }
                   float stock_min_level = 0;
                   try { stock_min_level = Convert.ToSingle(drc["stock_min_level"]); }
                   catch { }
                   float stock_worning_level = 0;
                   try { stock_min_level = Convert.ToSingle(drc["stock_worning_level"]); }
                   catch { }
                   float unit_det_conv1 = 0;
                   try { stock_min_level = Convert.ToSingle(drc["unit_det_conv1"]); }
                   catch { }
                   float unit_det_conv2 = 0;
                   try { stock_min_level = Convert.ToSingle(drc["unit_det_conv2"]); }
                   catch { }
                   string spe_code = "";
                   try { spe_code = Convert.ToString(drc["spe_code"]); }
                   catch { }
                   string group_code = "";
                   try { group_code = Convert.ToString(drc["group_code"]); }
                   catch { }
                   string security_code = "";
                   try { security_code = Convert.ToString(drc["security_code"]); }
                   catch { }
                   string mat_last_trans_date = "";
                   try { mat_last_trans_date = Convert.ToString(drc["mat_last_trans_date"]); }
                   catch { }
                   string bar_barcode = "";
                   try { bar_barcode = Convert.ToString(drc["bar_barcode"]); }
                   catch { }
                   float mat_auto_price = 0;
                   try { mat_auto_price = Convert.ToSingle(drc["mat_auto_price"]); }
                   catch { }
                   string spe_code1 = "";
                   try { spe_code1 = Convert.ToString(drc["spe_code1"]); }
                   catch { }
                   string spe_code2 = "";
                   try { spe_code2 = Convert.ToString(drc["spe_code2"]); }
                   catch { }
                   string spe_code3 = "";
                   try { spe_code3 = Convert.ToString(drc["spe_code3"]); }
                   catch { }
                   string spe_code4 = "";
                   try { spe_code4 = Convert.ToString(drc["spe_code4"]); }
                   catch { }
                   string spe_code5 = "";
                   try { spe_code5 = Convert.ToString(drc["spe_code5"]); }
                   catch { }
                   string spe_code6 = "";
                   try { spe_code6 = Convert.ToString(drc["spe_code6"]); }
                   catch { }
                   string spe_code7 = "";
                   try { spe_code7 = Convert.ToString(drc["spe_code7"]); }
                   catch { }
                   string spe_code8 = "";
                   try { spe_code8 = Convert.ToString(drc["spe_code8"]); }
                   catch { }
                   string spe_code9 = "";
                   try { spe_code9 = Convert.ToString(drc["spe_code9"]); }
                   catch { }
                   string spe_code10 = "";
                   try { spe_code10 = Convert.ToString(drc["spe_code10"]); }
                   catch { }
                   string mat_name_lang1 = "";
                   try { mat_name_lang1 = Convert.ToString(drc["mat_name_lang1"]); }
                   catch { }
                   string mat_name_lang2 = "";
                   try { mat_name_lang2 = Convert.ToString(drc["mat_name_lang2"]); }
                   catch { }
                   string mat_name_lang3 = "";
                   try { mat_name_lang3 = Convert.ToString(drc["mat_name_lang3"]); }
                   catch { }
                   string mat_name_lang4 = "";
                   try { mat_name_lang4 = Convert.ToString(drc["mat_name_lang4"]); }
                   catch { }
                   string mat_name_lang5 = "";
                   try { mat_name_lang5 = Convert.ToString(drc["mat_name_lang5"]); }
                   catch { }
                   int mat_auto_production = 0;
                   try { mat_auto_production = Convert.ToInt32(drc["mat_auto_production"]); }
                   catch { }
                   float mat_whousetotal_amount_2 = 0;
                   try { mat_whousetotal_amount_2 = Convert.ToSingle(drc["mat_whousetotal_amount_2"]); }
                   catch { }
                   float mat_tot_purch_avg_price = 0;
                   try { mat_tot_purch_avg_price = Convert.ToSingle(drc["mat_tot_purch_avg_price"]); }
                   catch { }
                   float sale_total = 0;
                   try { sale_total = Convert.ToSingle(drc["sale_total"]); }
                   catch { }
                   float purch_total = 0;
                   try { purch_total = Convert.ToSingle(drc["purch_total"]); }
                   catch { }
                   SplashScreenManager.Default.SendCommand(WaitForm1.WaitFormCommand.SetLabelText, material_name);
                   dk_Query.sp_dk_add_materialsMYSQL(material_id, material_code, material_name, m_cat_name, a_status_name,
                                                firm_id, m_cat_id, unit_id, a_status_id, mat_whousetotal_id, mat_whousetotal_amount
                                               , sale_price, mat_purch_price, wh_id, p_id, unit_det_id, unit_det_code
                                               , unit_det_name, unit_code, stock_max_level, stock_min_level, stock_worning_level
                                               , unit_det_conv1, unit_det_conv2, spe_code, group_code, security_code, mat_last_trans_date
                                               , bar_barcode, mat_auto_price, spe_code1, spe_code2, spe_code3, spe_code4, spe_code5, spe_code6
                                               , spe_code7, spe_code8, spe_code9, spe_code10, mat_name_lang1, mat_name_lang2, mat_name_lang3
                                               , mat_name_lang4, mat_name_lang5, mat_auto_production, mat_whousetotal_amount_2, mat_tot_purch_avg_price
                                               , sale_total, purch_total, modify_date);
                   dk_Query.sp_dk_add_materialsMSSQL(material_id, material_code, material_name, m_cat_name, a_status_name,
                                                firm_id, m_cat_id, unit_id, a_status_id, mat_whousetotal_id, mat_whousetotal_amount
                                               , sale_price, mat_purch_price, wh_id, p_id, unit_det_id, unit_det_code
                                               , unit_det_name, unit_code, stock_max_level, stock_min_level, stock_worning_level
                                               , unit_det_conv1, unit_det_conv2, spe_code, group_code, security_code, mat_last_trans_date
                                               , bar_barcode, mat_auto_price, spe_code1, spe_code2, spe_code3, spe_code4, spe_code5, spe_code6
                                               , spe_code7, spe_code8, spe_code9, spe_code10, mat_name_lang1, mat_name_lang2, mat_name_lang3
                                               , mat_name_lang4, mat_name_lang5, mat_auto_production, mat_whousetotal_amount_2, mat_tot_purch_avg_price
                                               , sale_total, purch_total, modify_date);
               }

           }
       }
       SplashScreenManager.CloseForm();

   }
   ```

Comment: Откуда у вас вообще появился MySQL и что вы пытаетесь сделать-то?

Comment: Пытаюсь перекинуть некоторые таблицы с MSSQL в базу на MYSQL. MYSQL-ом пользуются остальные устройства которые находятся вне локальной сети (это конечно не важно). Надо с одной программы который на MSSQL кинуть данные на MYSQL

Comment: У вас MySQL смотрит в интернет? Мда...

Comment: Ладно, не правильно выразился. Думаю суть вопроса понятен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если задача в том, чтобы с одного сервера передать данные на другой, то, в Вашем случае, можно просто настроить [Linked server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff772782(v=sql.110).aspx) и обойтись вообще без C#.
**[Гайд](http://dbasimple.blogspot.ru/2012/01/linked-server-mysql.html)**

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Не знал про эту возможность